# How to Scroll Down 100vh with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

So I've got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Down-Champlain Regatta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topcontainer">
        <img src="Images/Kim.jpg" id="tom">
        <img src="Images/Kim.jpg" id="zach">

        <div id="head">
            <p id="a">Hello South Burlington. We're the</p>
            <h5>Down Champlain Regatta.</h5>
            <p id="s">And we've got a bold new plan for sailing education on Lake Champlain.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="down">
            <p>check it out</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <h5>Here's What We're Doing</h5>
        <p class="beginning">The most important thing in sailing is experience. Read all the books you want - you'll still need time on the water.</p>
        <p>The Down Champlain Regatta is a non-profit organization designed to give students, if nothing else, tons of time on the water. Its three weeks of all-weather keelboat sailing on Lake Champlain, something not offered in many other places, will teach students more than anything else can.</p>
        <p>This course is not for new sailors. It's for kids who know how to sail, but want to take it to the next level. It's for kids who want to move up into the world of keelboat racing.</p>
        <p>And at the end of the course, they do just that. The course finishes with an all-day, student-led race down Lake Champlain. This is a unique opportunity for the students to apply their newly learned skills, build confidence, and </p>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#down").mouseover(function(){
                $("#down").animate({backgroundColor: "#1363bf"}, 500)
            });

            $("#down").mouseout(function(){
                $("#down").animate({backgroundColor: "#e03535"}, 500)
            });

            $("#down").click(function(){
                $("body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $("100vh")
                }, 800)
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to make the page scroll down 100vh when #down is clicked. I've already done some research, and nothing has given me a proper answer. Is there even a way to use vh, or am I going to have to scroll to the element I want (#container)?

Comment: `scrolltop` is always set in pixels, so you would need to convert the `vh` unit manually. `am I going to have to scroll to the element I want (#container)` I would say that would be a much better solution anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to scroll to the `#container`, but maybe `window.innerHeight` could help.

To scroll to the `#container`, you can try something like that:

HTML button:

```
<a href="#container">Check it out</a>
```

JS

```
$(document)
    .on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body')
            .animate({
                scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 'slow', 'swing', function() {});
    })
```

Comment: How do I scroll to the container? I tried what Beppoz suggested, and I tried just scrollTop: $("#container"), and neither worked.

Comment: ..but @Beppoz answer should work as well - just reduce window/cell height.

Comment: I ended up setting a variable, height, to the window.innerHeight. That finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this one
http://jsfiddle.net/La0558tx/1/

```
$('html, body').animate({
 scrollTop: $('#container').position().top+'px'
}, 800)
```

Comment: This just moved it to the top of the page. I tried removing the .top thing, and that didn't work...

Comment: Because the body has reached the end of the page (not enough space to move down), if you add content you can see it's working http://jsfiddle.net/La0558tx/2/